# Problem with old code while installing Dock6

Tags: fortran, gnu-make, gfortran, configure, g77

I'm trying to install Dock6 (version 6.9) on Fedora 35, I got the license from the website, opened the tarball and followed the manual instructions.

As per the instructions I've run the command `./configure gnu` to create a config.h file which uses the gfortran compiler, installed the latest version of gfortran and run `Make all`.

The problem seems to be that the source code was written with g77 in mind and I get a lot of warnings and 2 errors saying:

```
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 20 at (1)
cdiag.f:388:72:

  388 |    50    CALL ME08B (A(K,K),Q(K),A(I,K),N-K+1,IA*2)
      |                                                                        1
**Error: Type mismatch in argument ‘a’ at (1); passed COMPLEX(4) to REAL(4)**
cdiag.f:15:72:

   15 |       CALL EC08C(W,W(N+1),VALUE,VEC,N,IV,W(2*N+1))
      |                                                                        1
    **Error: Type mismatch in argument ‘vec’ at (1); passed COMPLEX(4) to REAL(4)**
    make[2]: *** [../../../install/rules.h:44: cdiag.o] Errore 1
    make[2]: uscita dalla directory «/home/francesco/docking/dock6/src/mopac6/src»
    make[1]: *** [Makefile:21: utils] Errore 2
    make[1]: uscita dalla directory «/home/francesco/docking/dock6/src»
    make: *** [Makefile:14: install] Errore 2
```

so i read in the config.h file that it was also possible to compile with g95 and g77.
If I compile with g95, which I managed to install, I get this error:

```
    **f951: error: unrecognized command line option "-fno-automatic"**
make[2]: *** [../../install/rules.h:44: showbox.o] Errore 1
make[2]: uscita dalla directory «/home/francesco/docking/dock6/src/accessories»
make[1]: *** [Makefile:16: utils] Errore 2
make[1]: uscita dalla directory «/home/francesco/docking/dock6/src»
make: *** [Makefile:14: install] Errore 2
```

regarding g77, I just cannot find a way to install it, I managed to find a .deb package, converted it to RPM using alien command, but it doesn't complete the installation saying it conflicts with something in the system.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. The code is likely not standard conforming and does some nasty stuff in argument passing that the older compilers (including older versions of gfortran) were not able to detect. It may be possible to disable this detection by a compiler option. Regarding `g95`, you likely uave to remove the offending option from the makefile.

Comment: It might be possible to fix the code, but it is impossible to tell you how without seeing the code.

Comment: Note g77 has not been supported in decades. Fixing the code to work with gfortran is probably the best way forward.

Comment: Hey All! 
Thank you so much for the amazing comments. 
Unfortunately I don't think I can share the source code because it's under a license I had to sign, so I'm pretty sure I can't share bits of the code. 
However, almost like magic all those problems disappeared when I switched from Fedora to Ubuntu. 
I know this is not a solution, and I'm not sure either what caused this in the first place, but the problem was fixed instantly, never encountered that error, so maybe something went wrong in the first installation of Fedora? 
Anyway, cheers to everybody, thank you for your time!